# Get Ranges using separatedBy Function in a Text View

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the `components(separatedBy)` function to separate paragraphs.

```
let components = UItextView.text.components(separatedBy: “\n”)
```

This returns an array of strings. I am needing to be able to have the info for the ranges and also an ‘id’ for each one to be able to identify it. I have no idea how I would go about doing this. Do I need to make use of tokens somehow?

EDIT: What I mean by 'id' is just an identifier I can have to be able to recognise what paragraph relates to which component. This is because counting through the array would not be accurate if a paragraph is added between 2 already existing paragraphs.

For the range I am wanting a Swift Range of the separated paragraph. Example: `Range<String.Index>(3..<8)`

Comment: What do you mean by `id`? Kindly support your question with as example.

Comment: @PGDev just a number that represents what paragraph it relates to. So I can say something like Paragraph 1 = components 1(which would hold the string and the range).

Comment: @PGDev I added more explanation! :)

Comment: And what is the range here? Add an example so we can understand the problem statement better.

Comment: @PGDev Okay, updated again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more functional approach then PGDev suggested:

```
let str = """
Paragraph 1
Paragraph 2
Paragraph 3
Paragraph 4
"""

struct ParagraphModel: Hashable {
    let text: String
    let range: Range<String.Index>

    init(withText text: String, range: Range<String.Index>) {
        self.text = text
        self.range = range
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(text)
        hasher.combine(range.lowerBound)
        hasher.combine(range.upperBound)
    }
}

let components = str.components(separatedBy: "\n")
let models = components.compactMap { component -> ParagraphModel? in
    if let range = str.range(of: component) {
        return ParagraphModel(withText: component, range: range)
    }
    return nil
}
```

The `id` would be a `hashValue` of the model.

Comment: Wow, this is great. 1. When I print it I am getting these throughout...(unknown context at $100f33fa8) Why is this? 2. How do I call the hashvalue?

Comment: 1. which line causes the error? 2. it's simply `hashValue` property of a model. So if you have a model `m` you can get the hash value using `m.hashValue`

Comment: 1. It says it before every print of a paragraph.   XcodeProject.ViewController.(unknown context at $1024affa8)(unknown context at $1024b001c).ParagraphModel(text: "Test paragraph. ", range: Range(Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 4325376)..<Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 6356992)))]   2. Will this work as I will have a single model and need to be able to call each paragraph. Example. Model - Paragraph 1 then Paragraph 2 etc. I won't have multiple models. Using your above example that would be 4 paragraphs and I need to be able to access each one in a single model.

Comment: 1. This unknown context is related to something different in your project. 2. Don't really get your point. Now you have an array of models and can access the models then you iterate through the array for example. You can think about this array as a wrapper around the models. `models.first.hashValue` or `models.first.text` etc.

Comment: Aww, okay. I think I now understand. Thanks for your help 

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we've a text like:

```
let text = """
        This returns an array of strings. I am needing to be able to have the info for the ranges and also an ‘id’ for each one to be able to identify it. I have no idea how I would go about doing this. Do I need to make use of tokens somehow?
        EDIT: What I mean by 'id' is just an identifier I can have to be able to recognise what paragraph relates to which component. This is because counting through the array would not be accurate if a paragraph is added between 2 already existing paragraphs.
        """
```

Getting `components` from `text` separated by `"\n"`,

```
let arr = text.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Now, we need 3 things for each `element` in `arr` - `String, Identifier, Range`

```
    var requiredArray = [(String, Range<String.Index>, Int)]()

    for (index, str) in arr.enumerated() {
        if let range = text.range(of: str) {
           requiredArray.append(str, range, index)
        }
    }

    print(requiredArray)
```

In the above code,

1. we've used `index` of `str` in `arr` as its `identifier`.
2. Calculated the `range` of `str` in `text`

Hence, the `requiredArray` contains all the `paragraphs` in `text` along with their `identifier` and the `range`.

Let me know in case you still face any issue.